# Gradle dependency external project fallback module

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I write some code to fallback when a project is not present in local to use a module project (present on a repository), I want to create a method to call instead of this :

```
    if (findProject(':Project') != null) {
    debugImplementation project(':Project')
} else {
    debugImplementation 'com.group:artifact:1.0'
}
releaseImplementation 'com.group:artifact:1.0'
```

Something like :

```
debugImplementation tryProject(':Project', 'com.group:artifact:1.0')
releaseImplementation 'com.group:artifact:1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using [Composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). You can include a complete build and gradle will automatically replace the dependency.

```
includeBuild('../Project')
```

in your settings.gradle should be enough (where `../Project` is the relative path to the dependency) if the group and name match the ones from the repository, otherwise something like this

```
includeBuild('../Project') {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.group:artifact') with project(':')
    }
}
```

never used the latter though.

Comment: This will work with multiple BuildType ? (I've edit my post)

Comment: And it will handle when the ../Project doesn't exist ?

Comment: No, you would have to create a new Project, when you want to build this project, the included Project must be present as a folder and you could include the actual project too. I am not sure about the buildTypes though, haven't used Composit Builds with buildTypes :-/